# How to quote a message using telegram bot reply?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a bot and it works perfectly. But how do I quote the message which triggered the bot so that user knows bot replied to him?

This is my code which I use to return the message.

```
return res.status(200).send({
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id,
    text: `Hello, welcome to <bot_name>`,
    parse_mode: 'Markdown'
})
```

I want to quote that message in the reply like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sendMessage` set the `reply_to_message_id` equal to the original message Id you want to reply.

```
return res.status(200).send({
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id,
    reply_to_message_id: messageIdtoReply,
    text: `Hello, welcome to <bot_name>`,
    parse_mode: 'Markdown'
})
```

Reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Comment: thank you for your answer, I was trying to do this whole day, but it seems like there are mistakes in documentation as they said `reply_to_message` is used but the correct form is `reply_to_message_id`.